# Reading from file does not work as expected

Tags: c++

I have overloaded operator `>>` and I am trying to read a data from a file, i.e.

```
Store first;
std::wifstream in("file.txt");
in >> first;
```

Here is the code:

```
std::wistream & operator >> (std::wistream &is, Store &store)
{
    std::size_t vec_size; // size of employees_ vector
    std::getline(is, store.name_);
    is >> store.surface_area_;
    std::wcout << store.surface_area_ << std::endl;
    is >> vec_size;         
    std::wcout << vec_size << std::endl;
    ...
    return is;
}
```

`name_` is of type `wstring`

`surface_area_` is of type `double`

file.txt:

```
Euro AGD
1154,5
0
0
```

(I have set Polish $LANG, that's why there is comma instead of a dot)

And what I get is:

```
1 154,5
4 519 717 136
```

If I add `is.ignore()` right after getline I get:

```
154,5
0
```

My guess is that `getline` is causing a mess in a buffer. How to make this work?

Comment: given that you use wifstream, is your text file stored in unicode? getline consumes endline character so maybe it messes up there

Comment: Yes, text file is stored in unicode. Reading words with Polish characters like ą or ć works well.

Comment: Could it be that the space is the "thousands separator" in your locale? Difficult to believe, but it is showing like that... That might explain the first output, but not the second one though. I think there is something messing up with the locale settings vs file format.

Comment: @A.S.H Yes, when using Polish locale, space is a "thousands separator" and there is a comma instead of a dot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have found the solution. The whole problem was that in a file there was `1154,5` instead of `1 154,5` - and everything works fine after this little change (without any `ignore()`). What is interesting, though, is a fact that `11 541,5` also works fine, but `111 541,5` is being rounded to `111 542` (whyyyyyy).

Another interesting question is, why the hack `<< store.surface_area_` saves a number in different format than `>>` is trying to read it. They REALLY should simplify encoding in C++, it is causing way too much of a trouble. 
EDIT: It does not, it was my bad after all.

Comment: Good news. But I would never love to work with the space as thousands separator. That is going to be a real headache, Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with a thousands separator, I didn't notice the lack of a space before. We both learned something today :) Take care, mate